# Scrolling dynamic height div with dynamic height footer

Tags: html, css

I have two divs in a parent (flyout menu), both divs need to have dynamic height. Second div is positioned absolute to bottom. I need the top div to scroll when it doesn't fit with the second div in the parent. The second div should always get the height required.

My (simplified) HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="top-div">
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link... etc</li>
   </div>
   <div id="bottom-div">
      <p>Needs dynamic height since it sometimes contains</p>
      <span>ERROR MESSAGES</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4032o8bj/

I've searched around for solutions but haven't found one where I can get away with not setting a height for either `#top-div` or `#bottom-div`. `#parent` is `height: 100%; position: fixed;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to support old browsers you can make use of flex layout:

add to

```
#parent {
  ....      
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#top-div {
  ...
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

remove the absolute positioning of the bottom div:

```
#bottom-div {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/41udrh4y/

Comment: You can get Flex to work with older browsers by using the relevant -webkit/moz- box styles. May not work as well as the newer browsers but it is possible. https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/ except IE lower than version 10

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with flex layout but this sort of does the trick. When #top-div gets too long though, it slightly pushes #bottom-div out of parent. I've sorted this by adding a min-height to #bottom-div. Still causes some issues if both #top-div and #bottom-div is taller.